# remove Â from python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to remove **Â** and **»** from a column in a pandas dataframe.
it would look something like this:

```
   |                           special_character                           |
   | mobileapps (new ad unit) Â» en-ca Â» alerts Â» severe-outlookdesktop  |
   | mobileapps (new ad unit) Â» fr-ca Â» alerts Â» (video) Â» videotablet |
   | mobileapps (new ad unit) Â» en-ca Â» smartphone                       |
```

I've tried

```
df = df9['special_character'].replace('Â', ' ').replace('»', ' ')
```

but no luck

Is there other ways to remove it? I'm kinda stuck here.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `regex`

```
df9['special_character_remove']= df9['special_character'].replace({'Â': ' ','»': ' '},regex=True)
```

Comment: it works perfectly thank you. but can you explain how adding 'regex = true' makes it work?

Comment: When you don't use the `regex=True` parameter, the replace method will look for the exact match.  When you use `regex = True` it even matches the **substrings** of the series and changes the string.

Comment: what if i just want to remove the Â and leave the » in? I tried with just 
replace('Â', ' ',regex=True) and replace({'Â': ' '}
,regex=True)   but it didn't work....

Comment: @PiCubed it will work, you need just assign it back to one of the column

Comment: @BENY unfortunately it still shows Â even after I did that

Comment: @PiCubed df9['special_character_remove']= df9['special_character'].replace({'Â': ' '},regex=True)

Comment: nope, doesn't work. I still see it there